# Difference in methods for converting std string to char*

Tags: c++, stdvector, c++17, stdstring, visual-c++-2017

I know there are a ton questions on how to convert a std::string to a char* and through my research, I have adopted a few different options.  However, the only one that seems to work for me is const_cast from the c_str() method.

So I am using that for now, but would like to know more information as to why the other methods do not work.  What am I missing in my understanding as to why this isn't working as intended which seems to work for many others.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char* test = "Hello World";
    string testStr(test);

    vector<char> testVec2(testStr.begin(), testStr.end());
    // testVec2[0] = 'F';
    char* test2 = reinterpret_cast<char*>(testVec2.data());

    vector<char> testVec3(testStr.begin(), testStr.end());
    // testVec3[0] = 'G'; 
    char* test3 = &testVec3[0];

    // The only one that works
    char* test4 = const_cast<char*>(testStr.c_str());

    cout << "char* test: " << test << " [" << strlen(test) << "]" << endl;
    cout << "str test: " << testStr << " [" << testStr.length() << "]" <<     endl;
    cout << "=== conv testing === " << endl;
    cout << "char* test2: " << test2 << " [" << strlen(test2) << "]" <<     endl;
    cout << "char* test3: " << test3 << " [" << strlen(test3) << "]" << endl;
    cout << "char* test4: " << test4 << " [" << strlen(test4) << "]" << endl;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I know the pitfalls of using const_cast but it works for my situation at the moment.  I simply take the string from the user, pass it to a C API and do nothing else with it (no worries of it being modified).

Here is a sample of the output
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaiC8.jpg

So what am I doing wrong and is there a better way to do this?

---

**UPDATE**
Thanks to everyone for the extremely fast answers.  It seems that my underlying confusion was the assumption of the null terminating character not being in the new buffer that I was assigning to the char* variable.  Hence why my output was showing random characters after the string (that should have been my clue but it has been so long since I've done C/C++)

I also should have tagged this C++17 originally (since fixed) as that is what I am aiming for.  I did not have that enabled in my console app in Visual Studio which made the solution by Passer By below work.  That is the method I will use going forward.

Bottom line, changing my target to C++17 this works as expected

```
char* test = "Hello World";
string testStr(test);
vector<char> testVec2(testStr.begin(), testStr.end());  
char* test2 = testStr.data();
```

Comment: Please show some code where one of those method doesn't work for you, and we can try to figure out what you did wrong from that.

Comment: I suspect that you're assuming that a `std::string` has a terminating zero.

Comment: 1) Copy-paste the output into the question, not put screenshots of it. 2) Your `testVec2`, and `testVec3` does not contain the terminating `\0` character, due to which your `cout`/`strlen` calls, exhibit undefined behavior due to reading past the end of the "strings" `test2`/`test3`.

Comment: @molbdnilo It does have a terminating zero (one beyond the length) since `c++11`

Comment: `const_cast` shouldn't be used like this, it easily leads to accidentally casting away the constness of something really const. Instead, just write `str.c_str(), &str[0]` if you really need to.

Comment: _"...const_cast from the c_str()..."_ is UB.  Easiest portable solution is copy to `std::vector<char>`.

Comment: @RichardCritten It is? Even with the original string non-const?

Comment: @Galik: Yes and no.  It's not part of the string in the sense that iterating from begin() to end() will not return it.  It is, in the sense that address arithmetic on front() can (reliably) reach it.

Comment: @RichardCritten As far as I know, it is UB to **modify** the `const` objects, not the cast itself.

Comment: @RichardCritten It is only UB if the string was declared `const`. Otherwise it is fine but definitely **not** recommended.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I didn't want to use const_cast but it was the only thing working at first.  I've since updated my code (and confirmed it) with the suggestions here.  Thank you to everyone.  I also updated my question to reflect the answer I used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
vector<char> testVec2(testStr.begin(), testStr.end());
```

this will create the following vector:

```
vector<char> testVec2 = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'};
```

Anything jumps at you from that? It should. It doesn't contain the null terminator character. Any attempt to use `testVec2.data()` as a C string will result in Undefined Behavior because of this.

Although from `C++11` `std::string`'s underlying buffer has to contain the null terminator character, the `begin - end` range doesn't include it.

Comment: A fix is `vector<char> testVec2(&testStr.front(), (&testStr.back())+2);` ... although that only works if the string is non-empty.

Comment: @MartinBonner wouldn't it be easier to just push_back(0)? ;)

Answer (score 3):

In C++17, the simplest way to fetch a `char*` from a `std::string` is simply

```
std::string str = "Why is this only available since C++17?";
some_c_function(str.data());
```

As to why other methods don't work, refer to [bolov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47332539/4832499)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I tried this previously but didn't have C++17 enabled on my IDE which is why I assumed it didn't work.  As I said above, changing the target platform made this work which is what I am using currently.  Shame I can't accept two answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Since `c++11` the best way to get a *non-const* `char*` from a `std::string` is to use this:

```
std::string s = "hello";

my_non_const_correct_c_function(&s[0]); // better than using const_cast
```

With a `const_cast` you can run into *undefined behavior* if you use it on a `std::string` that was not declared `const`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, is the terminating `\0` guaranteed to be there without a call to `std::string::c_str`?

Comment: @PasserBy Since `c++11` yes it is guaranteed. The question is about `c++17` so...

Comment: @bolov Ah, lol okay, note taken. I added a disclaimer that this method needs `C++11` or above.